# Option to discard goes away after discarding a new question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, asking-questions, draft

When I enter question text in the Ask Question page and then discard, the discard link goes away and doesn't come back, even when I enter a new question.  I have to leave the page and come back in order to get the discard link.  Eventually the discard link does come back, but only after a bunch of typing.

I think the discard link should always be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discard is for discarding a saved draft (server-side).  This happens on an interval so the link will not show up again until it will actually do something.  For example, if you left the page while the link didn't show up yet, your work would *not* be saved (an interval hasn't passed saving your progress server-side).

We don't want to show the discard link and lie that it's actually doing something, since leaving the page has the same effect should you choose...and no additional action is necessary to throw away your work so far.  Honestly we were very "meh" on even having a discard link on that page, but added it for convenience of clearing drafts (which we would otherwise repopulate the boxes with when reloading the page).

Comment: Hmmm... I've also been using the link for simply clearing the form (that's what I thought it was for).  Should there be a clear link, then?